# Laggy Multitasking View / Window Overview

Tags: pantheon, graphics, release-odin, multitasking-view

I installed elementary OS 6 Odin last night but I have observed that pressing Super + W brings up a very choppy overview of the Windows. Using the Multitasking View (Super + X) also shows the windows in a very choppy way.

My laptop specs are

- CPU: Intel i3-4005U (2 cores with hyperthreading enabled) @ 1.600Ghz
- GPU: Intel HD 4400 (Haswell-ULT)
- Resolution: 1366x768
- Kernel: 5.11.0.25-generic
- Memory: 8GB

I haven't modified anything system-level and Pantheon isn't exactly a heavy DE. It couldn't be my laptop either as I can run the prior Juno release without lag like this at all. Could be an incompatible kernel? Please help